# Hide / Show tab contents based on PHP variable value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tabs

I include one tab and display corresponding contents when user click on the tab. Here is the code for tab and contents.

HTML

```
<ul class="tabs" id="tab">
    <li rel="tab1"><a id="t1" href="#" title="Login via 2FA" class="<?php echo $FAActive; ?>" onclick="CngClass(this);">Login via 2FA</a></li>
    <?php if ($useSMS == true) { ?>
        <li rel="tab2"><a id="t2" href="#" title="Login via SMS" class="<?php echo $SMSActive; ?>" onclick="CngClass(this);">Login via SMS</a></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content"> 
        <div class="form_settings">
            <h3>Secure Login via 2FA</h3>
            <p>Please use your 2FA device (mobile phone or computer).
            <p>Enter the security code: <input type="text" name="otp" value="" />
            <p><input class="submit" type="submit" name="2FAlogin" value="Enter" /></p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #tab1 -->
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content"> 
        <div class="form_settings">
            <h3>Secure ID from SMS</h3>
            <p>Please click on the button "Resend SMS".
            <p>The system will send SMS-OTP to your mobile number (<?php echo $MobileNumber; ?>). 
            <p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">SMS-OTP Code: <input type="text" name="passcode" value="" /></p>
            <p>
                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="SMSlogin" value="Sign In" />
                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="Resend" value="Resend SMS" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #tab2 -->
</form>
```

Javacsript

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".tab_content").hide();
            $(".tab_content:first").show();


            $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {                    
                $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".tab_content").hide();
                var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
                $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();
            });
        });

        function CngClass(obj) {
            var list = document.getElementById("tab").getElementsByTagName('a');

            for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                list[i].className = '';
            }

            obj.className = 'active';
        }

        /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['Resend'])) {
    $FAActive = "";
    $SMSActive = "active";
}

if (isset($_POST['2FAlogin'])) {
    $FAActive = "active";
    $SMSActive = "";
}
```

I need to display the content based on this `$FAActive`, `$SMSActive`. Whenever I refresh the page, its tab content will display by default. I would like to change this to, for `$FAActive` is active then selected tab will be tab1 and for `$SMSActive` selected tab will be tab2.

I put this code inside javascript `<?php if(!empty($FAActive)) { ?> $(".tab_content:first").show(); <?php } else { ?> $(".tab_content:second").show(); <?php } ?>`  But it won't display anything. Anybody Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: `$(".tab_content:second")` doesn't exist in jQuery , the correct syntax is using [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) : `$(".tab_content:nth-child(2)")`.

Comment: there is a for loop in CngClass()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you need to modify.

1. Hide the tab contents. (You have done this already through .hide(), but I'd recommend you to hide it through CSS.) .tab_content{display:none}
2. Choose the tab content you want to display initially. This can be achieved by using the "rel" tag value you have used in parent li of the active link and show it.

   var activeContent = $("#tab .active").parent("li").attr("rel");
   console.log(activeContent);
   $("#"+activeContent).show();

Demonstration : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYyWOP
**I have ommitted the PHP part, you can manually set class as "active"/"" to see the change.**

Your PHP files are all good.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

 //           $(".tab_content").hide();
 //           $(".tab_content:first").show();

            var activeContent = $("#tab .active").parent("li").attr("rel");
  console.log(activeContent);
  $("#"+activeContent).show();
            $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {                    
                $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".tab_content").hide();
                var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
                $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();
            });
        });

        function CngClass(obj) {
            var list = document.getElementById("tab").getElementsByTagName('a');

            for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                list[i].className = '';
            }

            obj.className = 'active';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript for initial state. It will be ugly if script loads too long anyway. Better to do it like:

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content" <?php if(empty( $FAActive ) ) echo 'style="display:none"'; ?>> 

<div id="tab2" class="tab_content" <?php if(!empty( $FAActive ) ) echo 'style="display:none"'; ?>>
```

jQuery-s hide apply-s exactly the same inline style anyway

Comment: As per your code For the first time also i can see only one div. Actually this will happen only after form submission, depends on the form submission i want to hide one div.

Comment: I am sure you can tweak it to show both if post doesn't exist, i just wanted to show the idea, if you want i can make it as full working code

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript works on a client, but PHP works on a server side.
You can modify your html-code like this:

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content <?php echo $FAActive;?>">
...
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content <?php echo $SMSActive;?>">
```

In JavaScript you need to remove initialization part:

```
$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show();
```

And add to CSS rules:

```
.tab{display:none;}
.tab.active{display:block;}
```

But I need to noted about this style (when you check string vars) isn't best way, but it works if you'll be carefull. And you need to initial your vars before by empty values.